# Automatic registration of objects in C++

Tags: c++

I have got a class that represents a coordinate system defined like so:

CoordinateSystem.hpp:

```
#ifndef COORDINATESYSTEM_H
#define COORDINATESYSTEM_H

#include <string>

class CoordinateSystem
{
    protected:
        std::string name;

    public:
        CoordinateSystem(std::string csName);
        std::string get_Name(void);
};

#endif
```

I also have another class that I want to use as a container for all registered coordinate systems:

CoordinateSystems.hpp:

```
#ifndef COORDINATESYSTEMS_H
#define COORDINATESYSTEMS_H

#include <string>
#include <map>

#include "CoordinateSystem.hpp"

class CoordinateSystems
{
    private:
        std::map<std::string, CoordinateSystem*> csMap;

    public:
        bool Register(std::string name, CoordinateSystem* cs);
        CoordinateSystem* get_CoordinateSystem(std::string name);
};

#endif
```

However, as this is currently set up, it requires me to manually register all CoordinateSystems like so:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "CoordinateSystems.hpp"
#include "CoordinateSystem.hpp"

int main(void)
{
    CoordinateSystems csReg;

    CoordinateSystem helio_eclip("HeliocentricEcliptic");
    csReg.Register(helio_eclip.get_Name(), &helio_eclip);

    CoordinateSystem* helio_eclip_ref = csReg.get_CoordinateSystem("HeliocentricEcliptic");
    std::cout << helio_eclip_ref->get_Name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to have all CoordinateSystem objects automatically registered upon creation, but am unsure about the best way to go about this.  I did think of adding something like the following:

CoordinateSystems.hpp:

```
extern CoordinateSystems csReg;
```

CoordinateSystems.cpp:

```
CoordinateSystems csReg;
```

This would then be available to any file that included the CoordinateSystems.hpp header which would allow me to register all CoordinateSystem objects in their constructor like so:

CoordinateSystem.cpp:

```
#include "CoordinateSystems.hpp"

CoordinateSystem::CoordinateSystem(std::string csName): name(csName)
{
    csReg.Register(this->name, this);
}
```

Is this an acceptable way to go about this? Or is there a better solution that I am overlooking?

Comment: You can make csMap a static member variable of class CoordinateSystems if you have just one registration map.

Comment: You are using the Factory pattern. Look [here](http://blog.fourthwoods.com/2011/06/04/factory-design-pattern-in-c/).

Comment: Consider to use smart pointer instead of C raw pointers, they make your life easier.